# why dest[i][j] = src[i][j] tries to access the same block in the cache?

Tags: c, assembly, caching, memory, cpu-architecture

```
void copy_matrix(int dest[ROWS][COLS], int src[ROWS][COLS]) {
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++) { for (j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
            dest[i][j] = src[i][j];
        }
} }
```

What's the cache miss rate when ROW and COL = 128? Given a direct mapped cache of size 64K with block size of 16 bytes.
What's the cache miss rate when ROW = 128, Col = 194.

I checked some answers, they say dest[i][j] and src[i][j] will try to access the same block in the cache. I wonder why is that? Say the cache is empty at first, it tries to read src[0][0], it's a cache miss. It brings from src[0][0] to src[0][4] into the cache. Then the program writes to dest[0][0]. Then, the first cache will be replaced by dest[0][0]? Why wouldn't it start a new line in the cache rather than replacing the first line of cache?

The answer for the second question is 25%. From the answer, it says because they don't get allocated to the same cache block. Why is that? Wouldn't it be the same situation if the write action replaces the first block of cache, and the read action brings data into the first block of cache?

Comment: Unrelated to the cache question, you might want to consider something like `void copy_matrix(int dest[restrict ROWS][COLS], const int src[restrict ROWS][COLS])` to tell the compiler that the pointers aren't allowed to overlap or alias.

Comment: `dst` and `src` may both be page-aligned, or start at the same offset relative to the start of a page (which is common for large allocations done with `malloc`). In a cache where L1d is only just associative enough to take all the index bits from the offset-within-page part of the address (so you get the best of both worlds of VIPT performance and PIPT non-aliasing), the same offset-within-page will alias the same set, so there's a potential collision.  (Or in a direct-mapped cache, a guaranteed conflict, since there's only one way in each set)

Comment: Your question doesn't state relative alignments of `dest` and `src`, but the answer makes sense if they're the same relative to a 64K region (in the address-space used by the cache; in a simple example they're probably not also doing virtual memory, just having the cache tags use the same addresses the code is using).

Comment: *Why wouldn't it start a new line in the cache rather than replacing the first line of cache?* - **A direct-mapped cache doesn't have a choice about which block to evict.**  The indexing function depends only on the address, and there's only one block that it can choose.  This is why direct-mapped caches are rarely used in modern CPUs; a bit more logic to check multiple ways per set improves hit rates significantly, especially in cases like this.  It's up to software to avoid cache aliasing.

Comment: I get much clearer when I see your answer. There is one thing I am still confused about, what makes the second question access different blocks in the cache? And why is it 25%.

Comment: Would you like to indicate an architecture. Before I vote to close the question as too broad.

Comment: I think x86 is the architecture.